# laravel 5.6 nitial project after downloading from laravel installer shows "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel-5

The laravel project 5.6 shows "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" . when its downloaded from the laravel installer .My system php version is 7.2 . what is the reason of this error your guidance will be very much appreciated.

Thanks and regards
Shabin

Comment: the main index.php located in public directory. So you can open http://example.com/public/

Comment: i have changed and tried that but it still remains the same.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan serve`?

Comment: yes that also shows the same result.

Comment: I have downloaded two projects  and both shows the same "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: well, that is amazing. Did you do something like this?
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`  `cd blog` and then `php artisan serve`?

Comment: The issue is resolved thanks for all your help